# On iOS, how to make a larger file (1MB) be cached when using NSURLConnection?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsurlconnection, nsurlcache

On iOS, I am trying `NSURLConnection` to load data from a web server, which are just PNG files.

All files will get cached, except one file which has size 1,173,084 bytes, which is about 1MB.

I am looping through 6 files: pic1.png, pic2.png, ... 3, 4, 5, 6, and then back to 1, 2, 3, ...  The files sizes are 1MB, 650kb, 450kb, and some smaller files.

It is being tested on an iPad simulator, so memory isn't an issue.

There following were already done in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:15 * 1024 * 1024 ];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024 ];

NSLog(@"Memory Cache capacity is %i", [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] memoryCapacity]);
NSLog(@"Disk Cache capacity is %i", [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] diskCapacity]);
```

and the `NSURLConnection` was created in `touchesBegan`:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request 
                                   delegate:self];
```

The cache sizes are 15MB and 20MB, which are much larger than the total file size, which is about 3.2MB.  I can see the file being cached if the downloading is done almost instantaneously, while the 1MB file went through many `connection:didReceiveData` and finally `connectionDidFinishLoading`.

Comment: I think this will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565740/nsurlconnection-timing-out-on-ios-6-but-not-on-ios-5

Answer (score 0):

NSURLCache has a meganism for deciding what files to cache or not. The maximum file size is related to the size of the cache. Try setting the DiskCapacity to 200 MB. You will see that the maximum file size that will be cached will also be increased. The only way to solve this is by implementing your own NSUrlCache. If you are looking for a sample how to do that, then have a look at  https://github.com/evermeer/EVURLCache