# NSURLConnection timing out on iOS 6 but not on iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios6

I have an app that used NSURLConnection and worked just fine on iOS 5, now that same code is getting an instant timeout in iOS 6.

Any idea on what might have changed between the two releases of 5.1 and 6.0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In iOS 5.1 and previous versions the timeout interval being set when the request body was constructed was ignored for one reason of another.

iOS 6 seems to pay attention and is more precise about the timeout interval so just make sure to set the interval to a value large enough to allow time for the request to complete.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                              initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]
                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                              timeoutInterval:60.0];
```